# SQL trigger update another table with same prime key

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_RENEWAL 
    AFTER UPDATE OF NEXT_RENEW_DATE ON SUBSCRIPTION_CUSTOMER 
    REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW 
    For each row
    BEGIN
        update Subscription_log 
        Set next_renew_date = :NEW.next_renew_date, previous_renew_date = :OLD.next_renew_date;
        "Where rowid = updated row;"
    END;
```

The table "Subscriptio_log" has a column "Phone_number" and "Email_address" referenced from the "Subscription_Customer" as a FK and PK

The case here is that I'd like to trigger an update on a log table whenever the subscription customer makes an update of their next renewal date.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't figure a way to select only specific rows to update the value of next_renew_date and previous_renew_date.

Is there a way to select the rowID or other ways to update based on the FK "Phone_number" and "Email_address"?

Comment: I also tried using "Insert INTO" method, but the PK issue would appear due to duplication of PK values when the same column is updated.

Comment: How is the `ROWID` pseudo-column going to help you? You would get the `ROWID` of the table that has been updated (`SUBSCRIPTION_CUSTOMER`) and not the `ROWID` of the logging table (`SUBSCRIPTION_LOG`) and you will not have the same `ROWID` for both tables. What you need to use is the primary key of the `SUBSCRIPTION_CUSTOMER` table (assuming that that is also referenced in the logging table).

Comment: I would question the design decision here as you normally do not want to modify rows in a logging table; instead you would insert a new row with the new state and that way you have a log of the history of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your PHONE | EMAIL combination uniquely defines a row in your log table and if the same data is accesssible within your database trigger **than you could update the unique record** in your log. If that is not the case **then all the log records having same PHONE | MAIL combination will be updated.**
This structure of the log keeps just last two changes made to your customer data (previous and next date columns) making all other history changes definetely lost.
Log table - Sample data

| PHONE | EMAIL | PREV_DATE | NEXT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1915555678 | john.doe@domain.com | 07-JUL-20 | 23-FEB-21 |
| 1995555001 | jane.doe@domain.com | 12-APR-19 | 12-SEP-22 |

Assuming that column PREV_DATE should be overwritten with value of NEXT_DATE column within same row of log table (if not - you can define the update's SET PREV_DATE command differently) you can try something like below:

```sql
Update 
    subscription_log
Set 
    PREV_DATE = NEXT_DATE,
    NEXT_DATE = your_desired_new_next_date_value
Where
    PHONE = subs_customer_trigg_phone_value And
    EMAIL = subs_customer_trigg_email_value
```

Regards...